# Qtreeview colored border

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I have a QTreeView that is filled using an AbstractItemModel. I want to highlight some entries by showing a red border based on an internal state.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
QVariant MyAbstractItemModel::data(QModelIndex const& index, int role)
...
else if (Qt::BackgroundRole == role)
{
    if (someMethod(index))
        return QColor(255,0,0);
    return QVariant();
} ...
```

Obviously this codes sets the background color to red and not the border color.

How can I set the border color of the item?

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to SaZ the solution is the QStyledItemDelegate.

My code looks now like this:

```
QVariant MyAbstractItemModel::data(QmodelIndex const&, int role)
{
    ...
    else if (Qt::UserRole == role)
    {
        return someMethod(index);
    }
    ...
}
```

and I have a delegate:

```
class MyDelegate
  : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
  virtual void paint(QPainter* painter, QStyleOptionViewItem const& option, QModelIndex const& index) const override
  {
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    QStyleOptionViewItemV4 opt = option;
    initStyleOption(&opt, index);
    if (index.data(Qt::UserRole))
    {
      QRect rect(opt.rect.x(), opt.rect.y(), opt.rect.width(), opt.rect.height());
      painter.save();
      painter.setPen(Qt::red);
      painter.drawRect(rect);
      painter->restore();
    }
  } 
}
...
MyDelegate _delegate;
_ui.myTreeView->setItemDelegate(&_delegate);
```